# More elegant way of dealing with query string variables

Tags: php, arrays, query-string

The site I am building is a configurator that lets you choose the color of certain items. It will have functionality to share your color config. What it will do is generate a URL with a query string, like `?plate=red&cup=blue&napkin=white` My code reads the query string and changes the `<img>` `src` value. For example...

```
<?php
//This stuff is just grabbing the query string values...
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$querystring = parse_url($url);
parse_str($querystring['query'], $color);

$availableColors = array("red","blue","white");
?>
```

This is my HTML where I'm using PHP to put in the query string color values. This code is also checking to make sure the color is in an array of the available colors.

```
<div data-color="<?php if( in_array($color['plate'],$availableColors) ) {echo $color['plate'];} ?>">
    <img src="img/tablesetting/<?php if( in_array($color['dinnerPlate'],$availableColors) ) {echo $color['plate']."_plate.png";} else {echo "dummy.gif";} ?>">
</div>

<div data-color="<?php if( in_array($color['napkin'],$availableColors) ) {echo $color['napkin'];} ?>">
    <img src="img/tablesetting/<?php if( in_array($color['napkin'],$availableColors) ) {echo $color['napkin']."_napkin.png";} else {echo "dummy.gif";} ?>">
</div>

<div data-color="<?php if( in_array($color['cup'],$availableColors) ) {echo $color['cup'];} ?>">
    <img src="img/tablesetting/<?php if( in_array($color['cup'],$availableColors) ) {echo $color['cup']."_cup.png";} else {echo "dummy.gif";} ?>">
</div>
```

What I'd like to do is avoid having a conditional statement every time I want to check if the color value is in my array `availableColors`. I guess just a more concise/elegant way of doing this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: What if you create a function to do it?

Comment: Since the data is coming in from a query string, you need to make sure you validate it to avoid any sort of injections. So, I think fedorqui is right that you should just create a function which accepts a colour parameter and then either returns that colour (if valid) or a default alternative is not. Then whenever you draw HTML, you can use that function.

Comment: Additionally, I recommend you get out of the habit of using unquoted strings. The $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] is only working correctly for you out of coincidence because no one has defined an HTTP_HOST constant, but if they did, it would break your code. When you are using a string, always use single or double quotes around it. If you code with all error_reporting enabled, you would be seeing notices from PHP warning you about this.

Comment: Yeah I guess that's what I'm looking for help on how to accomplish. How would I create a function that checks all of the query strings values?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getColorData($color, $type) {
    $result = array('color_name' => '', 'color_img' = 'dummy.gif');
    $available_colors = array('red', 'blue', 'green');
    if (in_array($color, $available_colors))
        $result = array('color_name' => $color, 'color_img' = $color . '_' . $type . '.png');

    return $result
}
```

Usage example:

```
$plate_color_data = getColorData($color['plate'], 'plate');
echo '<pre>',print_r($plate_color_data),'/<pre>';    // just for test)


<div data-color="<?=$plate_color_data['color_name']?>">
    <img src="img/tablesetting/<?=$plate_color_data['color_img']?>">
</div>
```

Comment: Ok I think this is close.. just wondering where/how you are getting `$color` and `$type` in the function.

Answer (score 0):

First off, is there a reason you are using parse_url....can't just just grab the variables via $_GET or $_REQUEST?

Secondly, if you want to validate your data in_array is a good approach.  A simple thing to clean things up is to simply move it all to your php area and then simply output the post-validated data to the html.

If I were building this I would run all this stuff from a database so you would query to database if a color was valid.

I would also consider generating the graphics server side via imagick or gd.